# Printing lines containing the least number in groups - AWK/SED/PERL

Tags: loops, awk, sed, comparison

I would like to print only lines containing the least number in groups. My files contains multiple columns, and I use the first column to determine groups. Let's say 1st, 4th, 6th lines are in the same group because the content of the first column is the same. My goal is to print out a line that contains the least number in the second column for each group.

file.txt:

```
VDDA 0.7  ....
VDDB 0.2  ....
VDDB 0.3   ....
VDDA 0.4  ....
VSS 0.1  ....
VDDA 0.2  ....
VSS 0.2  ....
```

output.txt:

```
VDDA 0.2  ....
VDDB 0.2  ....
VSS 0.1  ....
```

I think I can do this job with C using a for loop and comparisons, but I think there is a better way using AWK/SED/PERL.

Comment: if you don't care about order and if `-u` is available, this can be done easily with `sort` (tutorial: http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/sort-files-like-a-master-with-the-linux-sort-command-bash/)... in any case you'll have to show your effort to solve this.. and `sed` is definitely not advisable

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bothering about the sequence of the 1st field as per Input_file then following may help you in same too. Also this code will be looking for smallest number value for any 1st field and going to print it then.

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]>$2?$2:(a[$1]?a[$1]:$2)} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT1:*** If you want the output in same order as $1 is in, then following may help you in same too.

```
awk '!a[$1]{b[++i]=$1} {c[$1]=a[$1]>$2?$0:(c[$1]?c[$1]:$0);a[$1]=a[$1]>$2?$2:(a[$1]?a[$1]:$2);}  END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print b[j],c[b[j]]}}'    Input_file
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your code. I think EDIT1 may have an error.  I got "a[: Event not found." Also, the first code only produces the first and second column, but I wanted to print the whole lines.

Comment: Please check EDIT1 now, it will provide you the complete line as output, let me know how it goes then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{split(a[$1],s);a[$1]=(s[2]<$2 && s[2])?a[$1]:$0} END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file.txt
VDDA 0.2  ....
VDDB 0.2  ....
VSS 0.1  ....
```

Brief explanation:

- Save `$0` into `a[$1]`
- `split(a[$1],s)`: split numeric `s[2]` from `a[$1]` for comparing
- if the condition `s[2]<$2 && s[2]` is met, set `a[$1]=a[$1]`, otherwise set `a[$1]=$0`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU [***datamash***](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) tool:

Assuming the following exemplary input file containing rows with 5 columns:

```
VDDA 0.7  c1  2  a
VDDB 0.2  c2  3  b
VDDB 0.3  c4  5  c
VDDA 0.4  c5  6  d
VSS 0.1  c6  7  e
VDDA 0.2  c7  8  f
VSS 0.2  c8  9  g
```

---

```
datamash -sWf -g1 min 2 < file | awk '{--NF}1'
```

The output:

```
VDDA 0.2 c7 8 f
VDDB 0.2 c2 3 b
VSS 0.1 c6 7 e
```